# installing RubyGem on CentOs 5

Tags: ruby, rubygems, centos

My ultimate goal is to install Sass.

To do this I need to install RubyGems

To do this I need to install Ruby.

I installed Ruby with `yum`.

I then tried to install gem with yum `yum install rubygem`

The response is "nothing to do" and yet when I write `gem install sass` I get:

`gem: command not found`

I decided to try to install rubygems 2.2.2 manually. After downloading it, I tried to run `ruby setup.rb` and in response I get:

`Rubygems now requires Ruby 1.8.7 or later`

But yum does not seem to be able to install anything later than 1.8.5.

So now I'm trying to do this manually.

I downloaded Ruby 1.9.2 to my home directory and followed these instructions: http://howboring.com/post/1226760251/centos-5-and-rails-3-and-ruby-1-9-2

This seems to work, but the problem is ruby1.9.2 is installed in my home directory (i.e. `~/ruby1.9.3` not system wide.

Thus in the directory where I installed ruby 1.9.2 `ruby -v` still gives 1.8.5 but `./ruby -v` returns 1.9.2. And `which ruby` returns `/usr/bin/ruby` (I suppose I could replace this with a symlink that points to `~/ruby1.9.2/ruby` but this doesn't seem like a "best practice")

So my main question is where should install ruby 1.9.2 with Root Permissions so that 1.8.5 is replaced with 1.9.2 system wide.

My corollary question is: is there any easier way to do this? (perhaps install sass without install rubygems??)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can i suggest Wayne Seguins excellent [rvm](http://rvm.io) (ruby version manager). As the home page states:

> "RVM is a command-line tool which allows you to easily install, manage, and work with multiple ruby environments from interpreters to sets of gems".

Site has comprehensive installation [instructions](http://rvm.io/rvm/install). I've posted a truncated Set of instructions for installing on POSIX systems below, **but please refer to the projects' home page** as:

> "we have spent massive amounts of man hours debugging the installation process. Please use the install process(es) from this site only, as this is the only supported installation types and methods."

Install RVM (development version):

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash
```

Close out your current shell or terminal session and open a new one (preferred). You may load RVM with the following command:

```
user$ source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

test the installation was successful:

```
user$ type rvm | head -n 1
```

this should output "rvm is a function"

List all known rubies:

```
rvm list known //this will output a large list of rubies shortened here
# MRI Rubies
[ruby-]1.8.6[-p420]
[ruby-]1.8.7[-p374]
[ruby-]1.9.1[-p431]
[ruby-]1.9.2[-p320]
[ruby-]1.9.3[-p545]
[ruby-]2.0.0-p353
[ruby-]2.0.0[-p451]
[ruby-]2.1[.1]
[ruby-]2.1-head
ruby-head
...
```

install the version you want:

```
rvm install 1.9.2
```

You can set a version of Ruby to use as the default for new shells. Note that this overrides the 'system' ruby:

```
rvm use 2.1 --default
```

You can also temporarily use another version of your ruby versions

```
rvm list known //lists system available rubies
```

Choose to use another ruby

```
rvm use 1.9.3
```

RVM is a great tool, well documented, and actively developed, it handles a wider scope of functionality than i can list here, and it's a tool I use everyday.

Answer (score 4):

> I then tried to install gem with yum yum install rubygem

You have a typo in the package name, it is actually named rubygem**s**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use rbenv to install ruby and rubygems that you need 
https://gist.github.com/jpfuentes2/2002954